# Cannot Full-text search Vietnamese word in SQL Server 2014

Tags: full-text-search

I'm make sure that SQL Server enabled full-text search and it worked with English word. But when my database has Vietnamese word it does not work.

Example:

[image: Config full search with column title in Table_1]

[image: My Query when search]

Please help me!

Thanks,

Answer (score -3):

```
Select * From [table] WHERE title like N'%Tinh thông tin%'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.